# Bootstrap - logotyp in the header but not part of the li-segment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have just gotten started with bootstrap and have done the following website: http://www.kompaktbygg.se/test/progressiv/

I have 2 questions which are the following:

**Q1**
How can i make the scrolling to "#omoss" to stop directly at the ending of the background picture, not it goes too far down. I have created a div with an image inside, but it still goes to far down.

**Q2** How can i make a logotyp appear in the header at the left side (aligned with the text in the jumbotron), without screwing up the menu.

If someone could give me some hints or help on how to do this, i would be very happy.

Thanks in advance,

Best regards
AgatonSaxx.

Here is my code (note document, i could not post it here - http://www.kompaktbygg.se/test/progressiv/code.txt

Comment: Why you are loading 2 jquery?

Answer (score 0):

**For Q2:**

Does it work if you put it like this?

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"   data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Logotyp -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="...">
  </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi, well, it does not really work. if you look on the page now, the logotyp is on the right side. Perhaps this has something to do with me not using the "navbar-header" div, i am using the "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" to get the menu.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah okey, i changed to the navbar-header and now it works, only that the logotyp is a little bit too big, guess i can change the height or padding in the header-nav?

Comment: Hi again, now i see that in my iphone, the logotype gets very weird, it is not in the left corner of the menu, it gets centered. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this? (i am using an iphone6). Also the menu in the iphone does not work anymore :/

Comment: Are you using media queries in your CSS?

Comment: Not right now, i have been elaborating a little bit with it, but does not fully understand it. I got the menu to work again, but the logotyp is still centered and too big. What type of media query should i use for the logotype, and where to put it? (in my main.css file?)

Comment: <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">    data-target must be <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> so put  data-target="#navbar"

Comment: Thanks for the help. Any idea on the logotype when using a mobile phone?

Comment: At the moment I don't understand what the issue is, I visited the site with my phone, galaxy s5 with chrome and I have the same issue. I'll look at tonight maybe i figure it out :) and get back to you   ps: i'm at work now :D

Comment: Hi again HDStrange, thanks for the help. Have you had any time during the weekend to be able to see what might be wrong with the logotype? Kind of annoying that it is not schrinking and is in the left corner, instead of centralized in the screen and takes up a lot of space.

Thanks for any help i can get!

/Agaton

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. So try and put a class 'logo' for example to the image :<img alt="Brand" src="logotyp.png" class="logo">   and in your .css put: .logo{height:25px;}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
.logo{height:50px;}
  }    hope it works. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you, it seems to work :)

One other thing i have been wondering about, is there anyway to get an image to the bottom of the div, for example now on the site, i have created an "about us" div where there is a picture and text, and beneath i have created another div which is blue, but now i get this white line between the picture and the blue div. Any idea why?

www.kompaktbygg.se/test/progressiv/

Comment: The <p> tag in: <p><img src="adam_bw.png"</p>, has a bottom margin of 10px. Set margin:0; to that tag. When you don't know why something isn't right, right click on it -> Inspect element and there you see the properties of the object. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using brackets, so i cannot really inspect the object the way you describe, but i will try to inspect in some way that program works :)

Comment: Hi HDStrange, i am not sure if you will answer this, but i will try and explain what has happened. My navbar (when looking in an iphone) is now stretched all over the screen in the top, instead of being a little box. I am not sure why this has happened, do you have any ideas? if you look on the following page (zoom in, until the navbar gets as on an iphone): www.kompaktbygg.se/test/

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the depth of the navbar. Try something like...

```
.line {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
}
```

The navbar-header styles should keep the logo on the left hand side of the navbar - see http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ for example.

Comment: You'd have to add some margin to the top of the line image itself to move that back into position using this method